# Increment value colum by previous row in select sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have to find a way to solve this issue... in a table like that, i would see my column "C" increment his value on each rows, starting from a costant, adding value in column "B" and adding value by the previous value in the same column "C".

Furthermore ... Grouping by User.

For example: (starting point Phil: 350, starting point Mark: 100)

```
USER - POINT - INITIALPOINT
Phil - 1000 -  1350
Phil - 150   - 1500
Phil - 200   - 1700
Mark - 300   - 400
Mark - 250   - 650
```

How can i do that?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using Luca?

Comment: also post the table structure

Comment: You need some order to the table: what is it please?

Comment: And where do starting values come form?

Comment: I'm using SQLSERVER 2008 R2; I'll take starting values by a temp table, (TotalSum actual point for user) joined with my other temp table with User, Point, Date, Rownumber(part by user orderby date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support cumulative sums directly using window functions.  You can use a correlated subquery for the same effect.

So, using the same structure as GBN:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), UserName varchar(100), Point int);

INSERT @t (UserName, Point)
VALUES
('Phil', 1000),
('Phil', 150),
('Phil', 200),
('Mark', 300),
('Mark', 250);

DECLARE @n TABLE (UserName varchar(100), StartPoint int);
INSERT @n (UserName, StartPoint)
VALUES
('Phil', 350),
('Mark', 100);

SELECT
    T.ID, T.UserName, T.Point,
    (N.StartPoint +
     (select SUM(Point) from @t t2 where t2.UserName = t.userName and t2.ID <= t.id)
    )
FROM
    @n N
    JOIN
    @t T ON N.UserName = T.UserName
ORDER BY
    T.ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using windowing. The table declaration is SQL Server but the rest is standard SQL if your RDBMS supports it (SQL Server 2012, PostgreSQL 9.1 etc)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), UserName varchar(100), Point int);

INSERT @t (UserName, Point)
VALUES
('Phil', 1000),
('Phil', 150),
('Phil', 200),
('Mark', 300),
('Mark', 250);

DECLARE @n TABLE (UserName varchar(100), StartPoint int);
INSERT @n (UserName, StartPoint)
VALUES
('Phil', 350),
('Mark', 100);

SELECT
    T.ID, T.UserName, T.Point,
    N.StartPoint + SUM(Point) OVER(PARTITION BY T.UserName ORDER BY T.ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM
    @n N
    JOIN
    @t T ON N.UserName = T.UserName
ORDER BY
    T.ID;
```

To do this, you need an order to the table (I used ID) and a better way of doing a starting value (I used a separate table)

Comment: Window functions were introduced already in Postgres 8.4, not 9.1 (and partially in SQL Server 2005 as well)

Comment: +1 . . . The code is very useful, even if the answer doesn't work for SQL Server 2008 (added in a comment probably after you posted this).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select "user",
       point,
       case 
         when "user" = 'Phil' then 350
         else 100
       end + sum(point) over (partition by "user" order by some_date_column) as sum
from the_table
where "user" in ('Mark', 'Phil')
order by "user", some_date_column;
```

You need some column to sort the rows by, otherwise the "running sum" will be meaningliss as rows in a table are not sorted (there is no such thing as "the first row" in a relational table). That's the `some_date_column` is for in my example. It could be an increasing primary key or something else as long as it defines a proper ordering of the rows.